Visual Basic compare string to element in list(of string) which may not exist
I'm creating a new empty list(of string) and then adding and comparing strings to elements inside of the list. My problem is I end up in situations where I'm trying to compare a string to list(0) when nothing has been added to the list yet and this throws an index out of range error, which I understand the reason for. Is there an easier way to get around this besides the two work around examples below?
Dim TempList As New List(Of String)()
If (TempList(0) <> yourString) Then stuff
'this throws an index out of range error

Dim TempList As New List(Of String)()
If (TempList.Count >= 1) Then
  If (TempList(0) <> yourString) Then stuff
End If
'This works, but requires a separate check of the list

Dim TempList As New List(Of String)({"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""})
If (TempList(0) <> yourString) Then stuff
'This is better, but I don't know how many blank elements to add.


What is the actual compare for? Are you just trying to ensure no duplicate entries?

Depending on what you're trying to do, there may be a better approach than trying to compare directly with a specific element.  Most Linq selection routines have an "OrDefault" equivalent that will return Nothing if there are no matching elements in the sequence.

I'm tracking changes by checking if the string is equal to the element in the list or not. If it's a repeat I do nothing but if it's new I update the element in the list to be the string and do something else. This is a simplified example as my string is actually an element from another list and I'm using a loop to iterate through my string list to compare each element to the corresponding element at the same index in the temp list. Which is why the temp list could have 2 elements when I'm trying to check the 3rd element.

Maybe you could explain what you're actually trying to achieve, rather than just how you're trying to achieve it. Why are you just comparing to the first item in the first place? Seems an odd thing to do. It may be valid or there may be a better option but we can't tell without context.

This is some example code I've been using for testing. I ended up adding blank elements to the temp list before comparing my other element against to work around comparing against an element that doesn't exist.
https://dotnetfiddle.net/MpXc5d

It is not bad to check if the list is empty, that additional check is actually the best way to prevent your issue. But if the string is never Nothing you could also use ElementAtOrDefault:
If (TempList.ElementAtOrDefault(0) <> yourString) Then ...

Remember to add Imports System.Linq since that's a linq extension method.
So as mentioned i'd prefer this:
If (TempList.Any() AndAlso TempList(0) <> yourString) Then ...


If you don't want to use Linq then you can also use If TempList.Count > 0 AndAlso TempList(0) <> yourString Then
